# Discord.js buttons. How can I retrieve objects from message? Remove the button?

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

I still don't get how those buttons work. I have an file called `messages.ts` that should handle all my message related stuff. For now I only have one function in it that sends a message with a button.

Full code of `message.ts`:

```
import DiscordJS from 'discord.js'

const botChannelID = '000000';
const pointsNeeded = 400;

export function postEnoughActivityMessage(guildMember: DiscordJS.GuildMember) {
    (guildMember.guild.channels.cache.find((x: DiscordJS.GuildBasedChannel) => x.id === botChannelID) as DiscordJS.TextChannel).send({
        "tts": false,
        "components": [
          {
            "type": 1,
            "components": [
              {
                "style": 3,
                "label": `Zum Member Befördern`,
                "custom_id": `addToMember`,
                "disabled": false,
                "type": 2
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "embeds": [
          {
            "type": "rich",
            "title": `<:tada:988855833809002546> Neue Aktivitätsstufe erreicht! <:tada:988855833809002546>`,
            "description": `**${guildMember.displayName}** hat **${pointsNeeded}** Punkte gesammelt und somit die Chance verdient in den Member Rang gehoben zu werden.`,
            "color": 0x3b4ea3,
            "thumbnail": {
              "url": guildMember.displayAvatarURL() as string,
              "height": 0,
              "width": 0
            }
          }
        ]
      });
}
```

What I want to do is that the button can only be pressed once, after that the button should be removed and I want to somehow know that this button was pressed with the id/guildMember used in the message (not the one who pressed it).

If have found out that you can listen for button presses on the client with this:

inside my app.ts:

```
client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
    console.log(); // TODO
});
```

But I have no clue how to remove the button or how to pass the guildMember used in the creation of the message to this function.

I have the feeling that I can't do it like that because everything I see of button code looks very differend than my code. So what should I rewrite to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to remove the button. You just need to update the interaction component and remove the button.

Like this:

```js
await interaction.update({components: []})
```

And if you want to get the user who create the button it's

```js
console.log(interaction?.message.interaction?.user)
```